# Cucumber - Accessing injected context in After scenario hook

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber

I'm attempting to refactor a test automation framework I have inherited (Java, Selenide, Cucumber) from one that uses static global state for test data, to context injected test data using picocontainer. One part I am struggling to change is the framework dumping the global static test data as JSON after each test. Is it possible to access the injected context in After scenario methods?

Comment: I suggest sharing the relevant code, probably we gonna need just to suggest just to create a class field for the objects you want to manipulate.

Comment: What is `injected context`? A `context` in terms of what? And how do you inject it in your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this [10-minute tutorial](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) from the official cucumber site. This does not show you how to deal with injection but I'll base my example on that.

Say you have a context object defined like this (I do not know what your real object is but you are free to adopt my example to your case):

```java
package hellocucumber;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Context {

    Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(String key, Object value){
        context.put(key, value);
    }

    public void print(PrintStream printStream){
        printStream.println(context.toString());
    }

}
```

Then to be able to inject that object you should make sure that:

1. It either have default constructor or your injector knows how to instantiate constructor parameters
2. Classes which describe your step defs and hooks have constructor which takes argument of a class we're injecting (if you are using classic cucumber syntax).

Since we have designed a class that we'd like to use for injection (in your case it is your context) let's proceed to step 2:

**Step 2 - Amending Steps defs and adding Hook.**

Let's add injection to step defs:

```java
package hellocucumber;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

class IsItFriday {
    static String isItFriday(String today) {
        return "Nope";
    }
}

public class StepDefinitions {
    private String today;
    private String actualAnswer;
    private Context context; // We added this line

    public StepDefinitions(Context context){  // And this constructor
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Given("today is Sunday")
    public void today_is_Sunday() {
        today = "Sunday";
        context.add("Step 1", "done1"); // And this line for demo sake
    }

    @When("I ask whether it's Friday yet")
    public void i_ask_whether_it_s_Friday_yet() {
        actualAnswer = IsItFriday.isItFriday(today);
        context.add("Step 2", "done2"); // And this line
    }

    @Then("I should be told {string}")
    public void i_should_be_told(String expectedAnswer) {
        assertEquals(expectedAnswer, actualAnswer);
        context.add("Step 3", "done3"); // And this one..
    }
}
```

Alright. Here I added injection and some lines which put data to my context. Now lets implement a hook that would be doing nothing except of printing what we have collected.

```java
package hellocucumber;

import io.cucumber.java.After;

public class Hook {

    Context context;

    public Hook(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @After
    public void doAfter(){
        context.print(System.out);
    }

}
```

As you can see we use constructor here like we did in our step defs. Picocontainer takes care of passing our context object to that constructor.

This is basically it.

Comment: Awesome thank you, the constructor in the hooks class was exactly what I was after.